# How to convert Object array to a Custom Class array?

Tags: c#

I have

```
public class ABSInfo 
    {
        public decimal CodeCoveragePercentage { get; set; }
        public TestInfo TestInformation { get; set; }      

    }
```

And I have an Object array say "SourceType"

```
public object[] SourceType { get; set; }
```

I want to convert the Object Array (SoiurceType) to ABSInfo[].

I am trying as

```
ABSInfo[] absInfo = Array.ConvertAll(SourceType, x => (ABSInfo)x);
```

but error

**Unable to cast object of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.TestInfo' to type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.ABSInfo'.**

how to do the conversion?

**Edited:**

```
public class TestInfo
    {
        public int RunID { get; set; }
        public TestRunStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int TotalTestCases { get; set; }
        public int TotalTestCasesPassed { get; set; }
        public int TotalTestCasesFailed { get; set; }
        public int TotalTestCasesInconclusive { get; set; }
        public string ReportTo { get; set; }
        public string Modules { get; set; }
        public string CodeStream { get; set; }
        public int RetryCount { get; set; }
        public bool IsCodeCoverageRequired { get; set; }
        public FrameWorkVersion FrameworkVersion { get; set; }
        public string TimeTaken { get; set; }
        public int ProcessID { get; set; }
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It seems there is a `TestInfo` among your `ABSInfo` array?

Comment: It is another class..see update

Comment: There has got to be a better, more type safe way to do this then the big ugly hammer of `object[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your `ABSInfo` class by making it inherit from `TestInfo`:

```
public class ABSInfo : TestInfo
{
    public decimal CodeCoveragePercentage { get; set; }
}
```

This will solve conversion problems and lets you access the TestInfo properties directly on an ABSInfo class instance.

Answer (score 6):

You could use LINQ;

```
ABSInfo[] absInfo = SourceType.Cast<ABSInfo>().ToArray();
```

Or

```
ABSInfo[] absInfo = SourceType.OfType<ABSInfo>().ToArray();
```

The first one will try casting every source array element to `ABSInfo` and will return `InvalidCastException` when it's not possible for at least one element.

The second one will put in return array only these elements, that can be cast into `ABSInfo` object.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects. You can't cast all `object` to `ABSInfo`, unless all objects are instances of `ABSInfo` (or more derived class).

So either put null in your array

```
ABSInfo[] absInfo = Array.ConvertAll(SourceType, x => x as ABSInfo);
```

or do not add something else than `ABSInfo` to `SourceType`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your array contains objects of type TestInfo.
So you need to build an object ABSInfo for each TestInfo in your array.

In LINQ :

```
var absInfo = SourceType.Select(s => new ABSInfo()
                            { 
                              TestInformation = (TestInfo)s
                            , CodeCoveragePercentage = whatever
                            }).ToArray()
```